# How to make widget never go to full screen mode in Qt?

Tags: qt, fullscreen, qt-designer

i recently started to use qt creator to make a small program ,and i am trying to make a login screen where the user can't go full screen. i searched in the property menu ,but i couldn't find anything ,and searched the internet ,but also didn't find anything.

So you can say how to not go full screen?

i am using c++ to write the program.

Comment: Have u tried using this in the .ui file? -
<property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>900</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>900</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </size>

Comment: yes i have tried to make the maximum size the current one but the full screen button is still there and when i press it it goes full screen but the layout stays in the middle of a black screen

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the property to your MainWindow?

Comment: oh ok it worked. the minimum size was set 1 value below for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from abhishek agarwal's comment, you should go to the .ui file and set the minimum value and maximum value with the same value like this

```html
<property name="minimumSize">
  <size>
    <width>900</width>
    <height>600</height>
  </size>
</property>
<property name="maximumSize">
  <size>
    <width>900</width>
    <height>600</height>
  </size>
</property>
```

the full screen button will hide thus the window will not go full screen

Comment: Kindly select the best answer as correct. This helps keeps focus on unanswered questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
QWidget::setMaximumSize(const QSize &)
```

to set a largest possible size on your widget.

You can find the size of the screen with the following code and then can set the max size to half of the screen size or whatever you want to:

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
QRect  geometry= screen->geometry();
int h= screenGeometry.height();
int w= screenGeometry.width();
```